# Resetting Images using setTimer (onclick)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script where I have the images change when they are selected, however, I would like to be able to have these image options reset to the original image after a specific time interval. Code is underneath. I have the function set up with the setTimer but I feel like I am missing a line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

h1 {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

h2 {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 350px;
}
h3 {
position: absolute;
left: 155px;
top: 350px;
}

h4 {
position: absolute;
left: 480px;
top: 347px;
}


h5 {
position: absolute;
left: 335px;
top: 347px;
}
h6 {
position: absolute;
left: 35px;
top: 23px;
}


h7 {
position: absolute;
left: 38px;
top: 302px;
}

h8 {
position: absolute;
left: 162px;
top: 302px;
}


h9 {
position: absolute;
left: 286px;
top: 302px;
}

h10 {
position: absolute;
left: 410px;
top: 302px;
}



h11 {
position: absolute;
left: 547px;
top: 50px;
}

h12 {
position: absolute;
left: 547px;
top: 172px;
}


</style>


</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Reset(form){
form.reset();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(img, newimg) {
img.src = newimg;
setTimeout("reset",5000);

}
</script>

<h1>
<img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/NMIS-42-UX100-R01-simple%20BACK%20GROUND_zps5sal2wvc.png" border="0" alt=" photo NMIS-42-UX100-R01-simple BACK GROUND_zps5sal2wvc.png"/></a>
</h1>         

<h2>
<img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20NOT%20AVAILABLE_zpsphausbck.png" border="0" alt=" photo LEFT NOT AVAILABLE_zpsphausbck.png" onclick="changeColor(event);"></a>
</h2>   

<h3><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/MANUAL%20NOT%20AVAILABLE_zpshcff1oar.png" border="0" alt=" photo MANUAL NOT AVAILABLE_zpshcff1oar.png"/></a>
</h3>   

<h4><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/RIGHT%20SELECTED_zpsfm5vwnr9.png" border="0" alt=" photo RIGHT SELECTED_zpsfm5vwnr9.png"/></a>
</h4>

<h5><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/AUTO%20SELECTED_zpsemqkoegv.png" border="0" alt=" photo AUTO SELECTED_zpsemqkoegv.png"/></a>
</h5>

<h6><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/RIGHT%20LARGE%20MAT_zpsh3uqhrd6.png" border="0" alt=" photo RIGHT LARGE MAT_zpsh3uqhrd6.png"/></a></h6>

<h7>
<img onclick="changeImg(this, 'http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20INSERT%20SELECTED%201_zpse8cn43hf.png')"src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20INSERT%201_zpsoantviyw.png" border="0" alt=" photo LEFT INSERT SELECTED 1_zpse8cn43hf.png"/>"</a></h7>

<h8><img onclick="changeImg(this, 'http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/RIGHT%20INSERT%20SELECTED%202_zpsiwxrndok.png')"src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20INSERT%202_zps4eun1ouk.png" border="0" alt=" photo LEFT INSERT SELECTED 1_zpse8cn43hf.png"/></a></h8>

<h9><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20INSERT%203_zpsopq4v1w7.png" border="0" alt=" photo LEFT INSERT 3_zpsopq4v1w7.png"/></a></h9>

<h10><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/LEFT%20INSERT%204_zpsegxrxewq.png" border="0" alt=" photo LEFT INSERT 4_zpsegxrxewq.png"/></a></h10>


<h11><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/RIGHT%20INSERT%206_zpszndwmelo.png" border="0" alt=" photo RIGHT INSERT 6_zpszndwmelo.png"/></a></h11>

<h12><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u385/jfd7851/RIGHT%20INSERT%205_zpsx6fnngwi.png" border="0" alt=" photo RIGHT INSERT 5_zpsx6fnngwi.png"/></a></h12>







</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's the reset function? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show the `reset` function, or is that the line you're missing?

Comment: To add to the missing reset function, you're also closing a tags (</a>) without opening them first :)

Comment: I'm confused between whether to reset the timer or the image. Any recommendations on a reset function to use?

Comment: So, you actually have no clue what to do? I.e. this is a "please send me teh codez" question?

Comment: I can see how it came off that way, but I swear it's not. I'm confused by the reset function. I can see how to reset the timer as a function, but I'm not trying to do that. I just want to reset the image.

Comment: I just added the reset function I have been trying to use. I tried to call the rest function within image change function and I am still having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no form in the posted code. Even if there was, `reset()` resets only value of the form elements. Anyway, to "reset" a clicked image, you could do something like this:

```
function changeImg(img, newimg) {
    var src = img.src; // Remember the original URL
    img.src = newimg;
    setTimeout(function () {img.src = src; /* Reload the original image */}, 5000);
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy7aawkx/).

But there will be some troubles ahead, e.g. what should happen, if user clicks an image during the delay. Everything would be much easier, if you'd use [a proper method to attach event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of inline handlers.